# DirectoryIterator still showing 3 files when the forder is empty

Tags: php

I have following code to count number of files in a folder using php

```
$x=0;
$filepath=$uplaod_drive."Workspace/12345";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($filepath);
foreach($dir as $file ){
  $x++;
}
```

But even if the folder is empty it show 3 files are there and if the folder has 8 files it show 11 files.

I would be very thankful if someone could explain this ..Thanks.

Comment: Echo each `$file` and see what are they.

Comment: `if ($file->isDot() || !$file->isFile()) continue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to count only regular files:

```
$x=0;
$filepath=$uplaod_drive."Workspace/12345";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($filepath);
foreach($dir as $file ){
  if ($file->isFile()) $x++; 
}
```

or if you want to skip the directories:

```
$x=0;
$filepath=$uplaod_drive."Workspace/12345";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($filepath);
foreach($dir as $file ){
  if (!$file->isDir()) $x++; 
}
```

or if you want to skip the dot files:

```
$x=0;
$filepath=$uplaod_drive."Workspace/12345";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($filepath);
foreach($dir as $file ){
  if (!$file->isDot()) $x++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DirectoryIterator is counting the current directory (denoted by '.') and the previous directory (denoted by '..') as $files. Debug your code like so.

```
$x=0;
$filepath='C:\xampp\htdocs\\';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($filepath);
foreach($dir as $file ){
    echo $file . "<br/>";
  $x++;
}
echo $x;
```

Then as mentioned in the comment above by @Prix you can skip if $file->isDot(), and if you dont want to count the directories then also skip if not $file->isFile().

```
$x=0;
$filepath='C:\xampp\htdocs\\';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($filepath);
foreach($dir as $file ){
    if ($file->isDot() || !$file->isFile()) continue;
    //echo $file . "<br/>";
  $x++;
}
echo $x;
```